# how to run python script in ruby on rails from a react frontend

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, axios

I am currently writing a web-app with Rails backend and react.js frontend. Meanwhile, my project partner wrote some scripts in python to do some web scraping. I am thinking how can I run the python script. I have a customary action in one of my controllers. But now I am not very sure how do I call such action from my react frontend. I am guessing maybe Axios can help but I only know Axios can do POST and GET and not very sure how to define my own action.

```
class DeadlinesController < ApplicationController
  def import
    exec(" python Users/sherrywu1999/Desktop/pythonweb.py")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely possible. The safest method here is probably executing the script from a background job (sidekiq, resque, etc.).

If you don't want to set anything like that up I would recommend

```
fork { exec("python Users/sherrywu1999/Desktop/pythonweb.py > /some/path/to/output/log/to.log") }
```

Using this, we are not blocking the execution of your rails app. If you just fire off the script with `exec(...)`, the page will continue to load until the process exits which may result in a timeout or other bad behavior. Using this method allows your main ruby process to continue execution while the script is run in a separate process. You can then check the log output at a later time if needed.

Wherever you place this code, make sure to configure a get route to it, then perform a get request with axios to that path to execute the script when you want to.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response! However I get this error                                             
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "exception": "#<ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Deadline with 'id'=import>",
    "traces": {
        "Application Trace": [
            {
                "exception_object_id": 70267612091140,
                "id": 1,
                "trace": "app/controllers/api/v1/deadlines_controller.rb:13:in `show'"
            }
        ],

Comment: I add ***post 'deadlines/import', to: 'deadlines#import'*** in my route.rb and call ***axios.get('/api/v1/deadlines/import')*** from react

Comment: The problem is your route. It's trying to match `deadlines/import` to `deadlines/:id`. If this is the only method you have in the `deadlines` controller, make sure you remove `resources :deadlines` from your `routes.rb` file. If you have other methods in there, just add that post route to _before_ `resources :deadlines`. EDIT: This should be a `get` route also, you're trying to trigger it with a `get` from axios. Best practice would say you should only use a `post` route if you're updating objects related to that model.

Comment: Hello, the fork exec method has been working well locally. However when I try to host it in heroku it doesn't seem to work. Can I still use this method? How do I change the file path?

Comment: @SherryWu You could try placing the script in the `bin/` path of your rails app and use `Rails.root.join('bin', 'script_name.py')` for the path. You _may_ need to install another buildpack to run python applications though. I'm not even entirely sure if that part is possible on Heroku. If not, you could most-likely convert your python script to a plain ruby script to get it to work.